# junit (eclipse) test neither fails nor passes

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am running the test in eclipse. The jar and test are properly written. I have made sure that it is not versioning error etc. After I run the test, the console (in eclipse) shows that the programs ran successfully and terminated but in junit test perspective, in eclipse, the red button becomes disabled but the "Rerun Test" still remains enabled. There is no failure trace neither do I see the green bar indicating test success. Any pointer in this will help.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleTest{

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void validityTest() {
    String userInput = ValidatorCode.validateStr("validStr");
    assertEquals("theValidValue", userInput);
}
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. You may *think* that the test is properly written - that doesn't mean it necessarily is...

Comment: Thanks for reading Jon Skeet. Here is the code (I have edited the post with the code)

Comment: I'm not seeing a `RunWith` annotation on the class - is that deliberate?

Comment: I haven't used Runwith annotation before. I was doubting eclipse and the library setup but those aren't the issue. I did a quick read on Runwith annotation but please enlighten, how could I add Runwith on this test? Thank in advance againfor your time.

Comment: I've always used `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)` in Eclipse, but it may well be that that's not actually required. (Will test it now.) If you change your test to not actually test anything in the jar file - e.g. change to `String userInput = "not a valid value";` can you then test?

Comment: Additionally, what do you mean by "Aifter I run the test, the console shows that the programs ran successfully" - that sounds like you're launching an external runner, rather than really running the test *in Eclipse*. If you right-click in the class and choose "Run as..." -> "JUnit test" is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yes, I can test when I provide expected string myself as String userInput = "not a valid value". So when I do use the ValidatorCode.validateStr() I can see the console tab(eclipse tab) which shows (sysout) that the value is valid and the the top of the console tab(eclipse) show <terminated> ValidatorCode[JUnit] / Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/Jdk1.8...../bin/java but the JUnit tab doesn't show the green completion bar and the red square button still enabled. To run the test, I simply right click in the ExampleTest and "Run as..."

Comment: Is it possible that the code under test is starting some foreground threads that are still running?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes it is very possible. I've tried to use System.exit(0) in the ValidatorCode before the code finishes processing, to indicate clean program exit. I also used System.exit(0) in the unit test(dreading bad practice) but just to try out ...no luck in seeing the test complete in either or both uses of System.exit(0). I haven't tried getting handle on the threads and killing them yet though. Suggestions?

Comment: Well at this point I'd start trying to narrow it down by cutting out swathes of the production code until you find out what triggers it.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's not really the case though. I used a quick program to list all the threads and I do not see anything else running from the codebase.

_`public static void dumpAllStackTraces ()
    {
        for (Map.Entry <Thread, StackTraceElement []> entry: 
            Thread.getAllStackTraces().entrySet ())
        {
            System.out.println (entry.getKey ().getName () + ":");
            for (StackTraceElement element: entry.getValue ())
                System.out.println ("\t" + element);
        }
    }`_

Comment: Well as I said, you basically need to start narrowing down what's going on. You're basically asking us to guess... you're in a much better position to actually diagnose this than we are.

Comment: Reger that Jon, I copied you the code to check threads(narrowing down!) because you asked about that.

Comment: Right, but that was just *one* guess. Basically you should work to pin it down from here, removing more and more of the "real" code until something changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a piece of code where `System.exit(0)`was being used to terminate execution. Junit doesn't like that, apparently. I replaced the `System.exit(0)` with `return` statement, it worked like a charm. 
Having solved this problem, my further question would be, what's the logic behind Junit not liking System.exit(0)? System.exit(0) indicates clean exit or smooth execution of process(sans anything alarming), well! shouldn't Junit like that then?

Comment: As I understand it, that would immediately exit the current process, which presumably is the junit test runner. It's not that JUnit doesn't like it, it never get's a chance to say anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I didn't get you wrong. As of my understanding you have only one test, which is successfull. Now if you don't have the **toggle enabled** (check circled button in image), then you won't see the tests which succeeded. Make your test fail, and check again, failed tests should always show. [image: Junit]

Comment: Yes I did make sure of that. Thanks anyway.